# Query String operator assignment error

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm going to send back data to my sms gateway.first i have a querystring like this.

```
string mobileNo = Request.QueryString["msisdn"];
int dest = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["shortcode"].ToString());
string messageIn = Request.QueryString["msg"];
string operatorNew = Request.QueryString["operator"];
```

Then i'm going to assign a variables to it.

```
 public void sendReply(string messageOut)
{

   messageOut = "http://mygateway.com/api/mt?msisdn=mobileNo&body=msg&sender=shortcode&key=nvqow9rhfp&product_id=2116&operator=OperatorNew&country=us";

}
```

But i'm getting operator assignment error..

Comment: check if their is a value in the operator query string and it's not null

Comment: Can you paste the actual error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this.This  parameter is wrong.this param not supplied.

```
&body=msg
```

Please verify your Key & Product id with the gateway owners.